# XDEBUG - Ubuntu - INI-hierarchy

Tags: php, ubuntu, xdebug

I changed my PHP version and also XDebug on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. How could it be otherwise, now the debugging doesn't work anymore.
I used xdebug_info() to display the current values ​​for XDebug. Am now at the approach which INI I have to adjust. But no matter in which INIs displayed by xdebug_info().

**I enter a value for xdebug.idekey, it doesn't matter!?
Which hierarchy do the INIs follow?**
It's like pinching the horn of an ox.

And of course I restarted Apache.

Addendum (A):
If I enter the entry `xdebug.idekey="dbg"` in the file `/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini`, it does not appear in the output of `phpInfo()`. In Visual Code, however, it is displayed in the debugging console with `IDE-KEY => dbg`. However, this knowledge does not bring me any further at the moment.

Addendum (B):
Step Debugger is disabled `xdebug_info()`. I proceed as described in https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug with `xdebug.mode=debug`. However, the value from the file `/etc/php/8.1/mods-available/xdebug.ini` does not arrive in PHP.

Comment: @Rob My pictures only show where I get my information from. Because in complex structures it is easy to talk past each other. Here a picture says more than a thousand words.

Comment: I reinstalled Ubuntu. Now it works again. How long remains to be seen.

Answer (score 0):

> I enter a value for xdebug.idekey, it doesn't matter!?

Unless you're using a DBGp proxy, you don't need to set the IDE Key.

> Which hierarchy do the INIs follow?

In the order you see them on that page, with later listed files overriding settings encountered earlier.

> But no matter in which INIs displayed by xdebug_info().

You don't actually show any of that in your screenshot, only which files are listed.

Comment: Neither Visual Code nor NetBeans can be used. I only try to implement what netbeans asks me to do.
"Be sure that your php.ini file contains these entries: .." My xdebug.mode is according to develop. Switching to debug does not respond.

Comment: I go through the first mentioned INIs listed by xdebug.org/wizard sequentially as follows
```/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini -> xdebug.idekey="CLI"
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini -> xdebug.idekey="FPM"
/etc/php/8.1/mods-available -> xdebug.idekey="xdg"```
```phpInfo(): no value```